# What is the order of objects returned by parentsUntil?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' id='a'>Select all/none</td>
  <td><input type='checkbox' id='b'>Option 1</td>
  <td><input type='checkbox' id='c'>Option 2</td>
  <td><input type='checkbox' id='d'>Option 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

$("#a").parentsUntil("table").find(":checkbox") gives me { a b c d }, but

$("#b").parentsUntil("table").find(":checkbox") gives me { b a c d }.

What I want is to find the first checkbox if any of the checkboxes are selected.  What is the best way of achieving this?  Thanks.

Comment: What are $("a") and $("b")?

Comment: Please post real code. The `$("a")` selects all `<a>` elements and equivalently the `$("b")` selects all `<b>` elements, which is obviously not what you intented to explain.

Comment: You want to find the first checkbox; the first that's checked or always `a`?

Comment: @roasted: sorry my mistake.  I have updated it.  Hopefully it is correct.  The actual code is generated by ASP.NET and is much more complex and I wanted to narrow down to the actual problem area.

Comment: @Jack: I want to find the first checkbox object at the top of the "list".  My ultimate aim is to untick it if any of the others are unticked.

Comment: But your code should returns for both same result, just like here:http://jsfiddle.net/urHHS/

Comment: @roasted That changed since 1.9 I believe; before that, they were ordered differently.

Comment: @Jack ya possible as it is stated somewhere that order of object's keys is not relevant

Comment: @Jack You are correct: http://jsfiddle.net/urHHS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure to get the checkboxes in the right order across different versions of jQuery, you can use `.closest()`, which returns a single result from which to anchor the `.find()`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').eq(0);
```

Assuming that `$(this)` is the checkbox that's ticked. The first item will always be `a` though :)

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple.

First, you should know that this behavior happen only in jquery below v1.9.1.

`.parentUntil()` go through every parent until it find the selector. so what your code is like doing is :

**Step 1**

do `$('b').parent()`

**Step 2**

Find every `:checkbox` of `td` (the parent of `b`) and only find `b`. He then put it in array

**Step 3**

do `$('b').parent().parent()`

**Step 4**

Find every `:checkbox` of `tr` (the parent of the parent of `b`) and find `a,b,c,d`. He then put it in array `a,c,d` in array since `b` is already in the array.

**Step 5**

do `$('b').parent().parent().parent()`

**Step 6**

You hit the selector in `.parentUntil()` (table) so it stop looping through parents.

*P.s: it is pseudo code, $('b') is not a selector.*

To see if one is unchecked :

```
if($(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').not(':checked, :first').length){
    alert('one is unchecked');
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AuFgE/1/

Comment: Thanks. That is enligthening. How do I then find the first checkbox at the top?

Comment: This isn't the order that it happens at all... parentsUntil finishes before the checkboxes of the td are searched for, so you're left with a collection containing (in this order), `[ td, tr ]`. Next you find the descendants of those two elements that match the selector. Most likely an older version of jQuery is being used where the sort order wasn't properly fixed. All jQuery methods other than .prev, .prevUntil, and .parentsUntil return the collection in DOM Order, so since you used .find() last, the collection should be in DOM Order.

Comment: I know it is an older version. I know `.find()` is used last. My answer just show a a step by step alike too `.parentUntil()` with jquery prior to 1.9.1. It's a little bit hard to explain myself since im not a native english speaker.

Comment: I changed my answer for "is like doing" is that better?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: it didn't work for me.  $('#b').closest('tr').find(':checkbox:first') will give b.

Comment: Work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/AuFgE/ Are you sure you used `tr` and not `td`?

Answer (score 1):

Both ways of selecting the elements will return the same results, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BQKyc/

```
var listA = $(".a").parentsUntil("table").find(":checkbox");
var listB = $(".b").parentsUntil("table").find(":checkbox");

function iterator () {
    console.log(this);
}

console.log("List A");
listA.each(iterator);
console.log("List B");
listB.each(iterator);
```

Here's why they select the same elements:

First, you select either input a or input b. Next, you select all parents of either a or b until the table, which means the td and the tr in that order. Next you select all child elements of the td and tr (again, in that order) that are checked inputs. At this point, jQuery uses `$.unique` to ensure the collection is unique and in dom order, which puts them back in the correct order (this last part was added in 1.9, previous versions just make it unique and DON'T put it back in dom order.)

The reasoning for you seeing different results was due to a bug in older versions of jQuery. Newer versions now pass the collection off to $.unique rather than doing it's own check unique check/dom reordering.

Using `.closest('tr')` instead of `.parentsUntil('table')` fixes this issue in older versions by selecting only one element rather than 2. http://jsfiddle.net/BQKyc/1/

Comment: It changed somewhere between 1.8 and 1.9; actually I can imagine a few cases where you wouldn't want the elements to be in dom order, but that's another story ;-)

Comment: This is where it was fixed: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/5ed0450dc471f61e4c5d5df30df3f3294a3e6bd6

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment:

> I want to find the first checkbox object at the top of the "list". My
>   ultimate aim is to untick it if any of the others are unticked.

Try this:

```
if($('table :checkbox:not(:checked):not(:first)').length)
    $('table :checkbox:first').prop("checked",false);
```